# Getting a 502 Bad Gateway on Application Load Balancer on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-application-load-balancer, http-status-code-502

I've deployed a KeystoneJS backend on ECS using a ApplicationLoadBalancedEc2Service with CDK. I'm still pretty new to AWS and when I try to visit the domain, I get a 502 Gateway Error. I've attached my CDK template for reference.

From ALB access logs, I've deduced that the issue is coming from the load balancer. The access logs when trying to access api.site.com gives this:

`http 2023-03-12T21:26:46.354861Z app/B-Ec2Se-1SJSXLQPN0WT5/060ba3cebce00a91 104.205.179.68:59623 10.0.73.11:49157 -1 -1 -1 502 - 1051 272 "POST http://api.site.com:80/api/graphql HTTP/1.1" "node-fetch" - - arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:{ACCOUNT_ID}:targetgroup/Ba-Ec2Se-SJ5TSYWCXWKL/4dcb365548b7d993 "Root=1-640e4396-180891915fab0a8a2fdd61a3" "-" "-" 0 2023-03-12T21:26:46.197000Z "forward" "-" "-" "10.0.73.11:49157" "-" "-" "-"`

From AWS docs this says that the load balancer is causing the error, and the string of -1 -1 -1 lists a range of possible errors, all of which I don't totally understand tbh. The backend is KeystoneJS which consists of an admin panel and a graphql API. I'm assuming I've misconfigured something in my CDK template but I don't know what that is, and the documentation descriptions of possible errors from the access logs are pretty widespread and somewhat opaque, at least to me. Any help would be appreciated.

````
const vpc = new Vpc(this, "VPC", {
      cidr: "10.0.0.0/16",
      subnetConfiguration: [
        { name: "elb_public_", subnetType: SubnetType.PUBLIC },
        { name: "ecs_private_", subnetType: SubnetType.PRIVATE_WITH_NAT },
        { name: "aurora_isolated_", subnetType: SubnetType.PRIVATE_ISOLATED },
      ],
    });
    const subnetIds: string[] = [];
    vpc.isolatedSubnets.forEach((subnet, index) => {
      subnetIds.push(subnet.subnetId);
    });

    const dbSubnetGroup: CfnDBSubnetGroup = new CfnDBSubnetGroup(
      this,
      "AuroraSubnetGroup",
      {
        dbSubnetGroupDescription: "Subnet group to access aurora",
        dbSubnetGroupName: "aurora-serverless-subnet-group",
        subnetIds,
      }
    );

    const databaseCredentialsSecret = new secretsManager.Secret(
      this,
      "DBCredentialsSecret",
      {
        secretName: `${serviceName}-credentials-db`,
        generateSecretString: {
          secretStringTemplate: JSON.stringify({
            username: databaseUsername,
          }),
          excludePunctuation: true,
          includeSpace: false,
          generateStringKey: "password",
        },
      }
    );

new ssm.StringParameter(this, "DBCredentialsArn", {
      parameterName: `${serviceName}-credentials-arn`,
      stringValue: databaseCredentialsSecret.secretArn,
    });

    const dbClusterSecurityGroup = new SecurityGroup(
      this,
      "DBClusterSecurityGroup",
      { vpc }
    );
    dbClusterSecurityGroup.addIngressRule(
      Peer.ipv4("10.0.0.0/16"),
      Port.tcp(5432)
    );

    const dbConfig = {
      dbClusterIdentifier: `${serviceName}-cluster`,
      engineMode: "serverless",
      engine: "aurora-postgresql",
      engineVersion: "10.7",
      databaseName: databaseName,
      masterUsername: databaseCredentialsSecret
        .secretValueFromJson("username")
        .toString(),
      masterUserPassword: databaseCredentialsSecret
        .secretValueFromJson("password")
        .toString(),
      dbSubnetGroupName: dbSubnetGroup.dbSubnetGroupName,
      scalingConfiguration: {
        autoPause: true,
        maxCapacity: 2,
        minCapacity: 2,
        secondsUntilAutoPause: 3600,
      },
      vpcSecurityGroupIds: [dbClusterSecurityGroup.securityGroupId],
    };

    const rdsCluster = new CfnDBCluster(this, "DBCluster", dbConfig);
    rdsCluster.addDependsOn(dbSubnetGroup);

    const repo = ecr.Repository.fromRepositoryArn(
      this,
      "BackendRepo",
      `arn:aws:ecr:us-east-1:${ACCOUNT_ID}:repository/backend`
    );
    const image = ecs.ContainerImage.fromEcrRepository(repo);

    const cluster = new ecs.Cluster(this, "Cluster", {
      vpc,
    });

    cluster.addCapacity("DefaultAutoScalingGroupCapacity", {
      instanceType: new ec2.InstanceType("t2.xlarge"),
      desiredCapacity: 3,
    });
    const loadBalancedService =
      new ecs_patterns.ApplicationLoadBalancedEc2Service(this, "Ec2Service", {
        domainName: "api.site.com",
        memoryLimitMiB: 2048,
        domainZone: {
          env: {
            account: ${ACCOUNT_ID},
            region: "us-east-1",
          },
          hostedZoneId: "Z07240521MS2RP8F5K3FW",
          zoneName: "site.com",
          hostedZoneArn: "arn:aws:route53:::hostedzone/Z07240521MS2RP8F5K3FW",
          stack: this,
          node: this.node,
          applyRemovalPolicy: () => RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
        },
        cluster,
        taskImageOptions: {
          image: image,
          environment: {
            ...
          },
        },
      });```
````

Comment: Does the target group say your targets are healthy?

Comment: @MarkB No, it appears it is unhealthy. So I must have something misconfigured?

Comment: Yes, you need to look at your target group settings, and make sure your container is actually responding with a `200` OK at the address the target group is hitting.